# $_SESSION is not showing data on all pages

Tags: php, session

I am using $_SESSION array and on one page when I print array by using print_r($_SESSION); then it displays data, but on the same page when I include another page and that page also have print_r($_SESSION); but don't show any data. Means on the same page it shows data one time and the second time it displays an empty array.

Comment: Did you run `session_start()`?

Comment: sounds like you forgot the `session_start` but would be great to see example pages where it does and does not work as expected

Answer (score 1):

you should start every page with session_start();

Comment: Thanks for answer
But I am including that page in a page where I am using Session again.

Like 
My index.php page have code :
print_r($_SESSION);
include_once 'Header.php';

On this page, data is showing
But in header.php data is not showing